# Current Activity of Running PHP Process

Tags: php, debugging

I have a PHP script running that's taking hours, it usually takes a long time, but I'm unsure as to what it's doing or how long it's going to be.

I know I can see how long it's been running and memory using through "top", but is there any way I can actually see which lines are being processing right now in a running PHP process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

options are:

- log everything to some log file (before and after every line of code)
- use `strace` to check which system calls your process is doing right now
- enable `xdebug` in php and remotely connect to your script from some IDE which supports it.

Comment: ...or just log significant events / and/or snapshots of the state using a tick function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks